# Why do I have to re-install my Civilization V?

Tags: steam, civilization-5

I had Civilization V on C:/Program Files/Steam/SteamApps and I copied and pasted it from my laptop on to a new PC I bought. However when I installed Steam, it didn't register that Civilization was installed.

I tried [verifying the integrity of the game cache](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2037-QEUH-3335) but it was greyed out.

I could just install the game again, but I am tight on my monthly usage and a few friends that came over for a week almost completely used up my internet for the month.

How do I make Steam recognize the Civilization V files in the SteamApps directory, without me having to install the game over again?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC Steam verifies C:/Program Files/Steam/SteamApps for files that already exists for the game before downloading anything. So, if you try to install Civ V, it will detect the game files and automatically un"gray"out the game for you without downloading additional files.

Additionaly, you can try Steam instructions for transfering games between computers: https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7418-YUBN-8129

Also, I think this question may be relevant:
[How do I copy Steam game files from another PC while the game's still downloading?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/147692/how-do-i-copy-steam-game-files-from-another-pc-while-the-games-still-downloadin)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Move the appmanifest_8930.acf from the SteamApps folder into the other SteamApps folder.
Then restart Steam.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem, with a relatively simple solution.

I basically backed up my game by clicking Steam and then clicking the Backup option (Backup and Restore, or something along those lines). Then I moved that backup to my PC and converted that backup back into the game (The backed-up game will be in a weird format; you can choose between CD and DVD format).

Saved games can also be transferred, but must be done manually, by first locating them from the directory `[My Documents]\My Games\Sid Meier's Civilization 5\Saves` (on Windows version) and transferring them to the respective directory of the new PC computer. The default location of My Documents is `C:\Users\[your user name]\Documents` on Windows Vista and later.

Comment: You can always find your saved games from the directory C:\Users\\[your user name]\Documents\My Games\Sid Meier's Civilization 5\Saves. Just copy them from there to the new computer's respective directory (which should be created even if there are no save games yet, IIRC).

Comment: Oh really? That sounds simple enough, I should try that!

Comment: I now edited your answer so that it can be found directly from there

Comment: That makes things better for people who need this in the future! Thanks!