# Is there a way to download a Steam game from outside of steam then import it to Steam?

Tags: steam, grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

I bought GTA V from Steam 2 months ago and tomorrow I'm finally building a PC to run it.

So I would like to start downloading GTA V from today and then transfer it to my new PC tomorrow.

**Is there a way to download a Steam game from the outside of Steam (e.g. Torrent) then import it to Steam?**

Please note **I can't download the game from Steam** on my current PC, because I only have a 32 bit machine (Win10 OS).

Comment: @Kinan You can have a look at this answer https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/147692/how-do-i-copy-steam-game-files-from-another-pc-while-the-games-still-downloadin but be warned, you might still need to download the whole game in the end...

Comment: Thanks... I'm ready to risk it I have nothing to lose.

Comment: You can simply copy the game folder to `steamapps` folder. (Where all games are located). Sometimes it works.

Comment: Copying old steam files from one PC to another works, but often enough it will simply fail and you will have to reacquire the files anyway. Nowadays, I would not bother with this, unless your internet connection is too slow and you really want to start instantly. You could also download it in the background while finishing the setup..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently there's something called SteamCMD that you can use

Here's a thread in the [steam forums](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/617328967241853692/) about it

Notice the bit near the bottom about forcing it to download 64 bit on 32 bit

I've not used it so can't say for sure if it works.

***Use at own risk*** :P

Comment: @Kinan Yes, this works; can download for 64-bit machine from a 32-bit machine, for Windows from Mac, etc, etc. Also possible using the Steam client's "console" instead of using SteamCMD.

Answer (score 0):

if you have another comeputer running the same steam account you can download the game onto it and then transfer the files onto the new computer. There is also other application and programs that you can install. :)